# Will a USB WiFi adapter that works for other Linux distros work with Elementary OS?

Tags: wifi

Super noob question but I'm assuming the drivers are probably the same. The USB adapter in question is [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EQT0YK2). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If it works in Ubuntu (more specifically, if the tested Ubuntu distro matches your current elementary kernel version), it will work on elementary.